# Facebook graph get profile picture image type

Tags: php, facebook, php-gd

I am trying to duplicate and work with images from Facebook profiles. I can get the images just fine. The majority of them are 'jpgs' however, some of them are 'pngs' and even a few are 'gifs'. There may be others that I don't know about.

My issue. **I need to find out what type of image they are before I work with them.**

The below code works to get the image and with json I get the url... **but the last line of code will not work unless I have the right image type**.

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/$user[id]/picture?width=512&height=512&redirect=false");

$decoded = json_decode($json,true);
$url = $decoded['data']['url'];



/// This line will only work if the image is a jpeg or it throws an error. 
$source= imagecreatefromjpeg("$url");
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Grabbed from [Create Image From Url Any File Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233577/create-image-from-url-any-file-type)

> ```
> $jpeg_image = imagecreatefromfile( 'photo.jpeg' );
> $gif_image = imagecreatefromfile( 'clipart.gif' );
> $png_image = imagecreatefromfile( 'transparent_checkerboard.PnG' );
> $another_jpeg = imagecreatefromfile( 'picture.JPG' );
> // This requires you to remove or rewrite file_exists check:
> $jpeg_image = imagecreatefromfile( 'http://example.net/photo.jpeg' );
> // SEE BELOW HO TO DO IT WHEN http:// ARGS IS NEEDED:
> $jpeg_image = imagecreatefromfile( 'http://example.net/photo.jpeg?foo=hello&bar=world' );
>
> function imagecreatefromfile( $filename ) {
>     if (!file_exists($filename)) {
>         throw new InvalidArgumentException('File "'.$filename.'" not found.');
>     }
>     switch ( strtolower( pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ))) {
>         case 'jpeg':
>         case 'jpg':
>             return imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
>         break;
>
>         case 'png':
>             return imagecreatefrompng($filename);
>         break;
>
>         case 'gif':
>             return imagecreatefromgif($filename);
>         break;
>
>         default:
>             throw new InvalidArgumentException('File "'.$filename.'" is not valid jpg, png or gif image.');
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```