# What is GD library, how to include it and crop an image in php?

Tags: php, gd, crop

Hey guys i am trying to crop uploaded image using php using following code.

```
if(isset($_POST["Crop"])){  
    $source_x=$_POST['x_value'];
    $source_y=$_POST['y_value'];
    $width=$_POST['w_value'];
    $height=$_POST['h_value'];

    $src="assets/images/uploads/1509432972_Koala.jpg";
    $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height); 
    imagecopy ($crop, $src, 0, 0, $source_x, $source_y, $width, $height); 
    imagejpeg($crop); 
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($crop);
}
```

The problem that it is not working properly. Since there are lot of posts there to solve this, found a solution called GD library how to include it and crop all kind of images.

Comment: What is the exact problem ? include GD library ?

Comment: exact problem is couldn't crop the image using above code, no i didn't included it how to include and where to get that library? @tan

Comment: What errors u see ? if not seeing anything, please enable errors  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/8197560

Comment: error is already enabled, but i didnt get any the code is working fine i guess, some more thing i need to add, dont know whats that..

Comment: imagecopy seems to expect a resource at 2nd parameter, not the file path ?

Comment: $resSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($src) and pass it to there. for any type see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10247150/8197560